# How do you clean up tung oil that has dried on a concrete porch

Tags: stain-removal

A neighbor's granddaughter got tung oil on her concrete porch while staining the front door. Unfortunately, it's been a few months now and I'm trying to help her find a way to remove the stain.
I tried paint thinner and mineral spirits which is what is recommended on the can for cleanup - but no dice. Yesterday I got some concrete and driveway degreaser, scrubbed it and then power washed it. Nothing so far has worked.
I suggested she might want to buy a nice outdoor carpet to put over it.
Any ideas on what might work?

Comment: stain the whole porch

Comment: That is an option, but since it's concrete it'd have to be painted which would require constant upkeep. We're hoping to find a way to remove it.

Comment: have you tried using a wire brush?

Comment: Good suggestion - I haven't tried that. Thanks, I still think I'll need some type of solvent to break it down a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sodium Hydroxide helped to break up the dried tung oil but still left mottled blotches on the concrete. I followed that up with a muriatic acid solution and that solved the problem. I applied the solution to the wet concrete, scrubbed it in with a long-handled brush and then power-washed it. It looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Caustic soda.

Sprinkle on and dampen to a paste, cover with newspaper and plastic sheeting.
allow to sit several days, sweep off, scrub,  and rinse off with plenty of water.

Danger: corrosive: Keep away from aluminium, Wear water-proof gloves and eye protection.  Wash with water without delay if you get any on you.

Comment: Thanks for that idea - good suggestion. I'll suggest that to her and see if she wants to give that a try. She's also concerned about not harming her flowers with runoff from the cleaning.

Comment: @Jasen-Ordering the sodium hydroxide. One question: I understand covering it with plastic but why the newspaper?

Comment: just to help retain the dampness

Comment: Followed your directions but the tung oil just spread out over a larger area of the concrete. It's lighter in color but turned into big, ugly splotches. I tried a second application and power washed after 4 hours (didn't want the diluted tung oil to reabsorb) but it still didn't clean it. Now I'm thinking TSP or muriatic acid. Thoughts?